# MATLABにおけるデータ書き込みと読み込み

Tags: matlab

MATLABでファイル読み込みを行い、読み込んだデータを使って計算しようとしています。
以下のようなansを求めたいのですが、ファイル書き出ししたデータからだとうまく計算ができずにエラーが出てしまいます。

どのように修正すればいいでしょうか。
バージョン：MATLABR2019a

コマンドラインで命令した場合

```
>> A=[1;2;3;4;5]

A =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5

>> B=[6;7;8;9;10]

B =

     6
     7
     8
     9
    10

>> B-A

ans =

     5
     5
     5
     5
     5
```

事前にファイルを作成しておく

```
A=[1;2;3;4;5]
save('Aarray.m', 'A')
```

プログラム

```
Aarray = load('Aarray.m')
B=[6;7;8;9;10]

Newarray = Aarray - B

save('Newarray.m', 'Newarray')
```

エラーメッセージ

```
>> sample
Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file Aarray.m must be the same as previous lines.

Error in sample (line 1)
Aarray = load('Aarray.m')
```

ご回答を受けて
すぐに実行できる環境がMacのMATLABだったので、.txt拡張子で保存し実行したのですが、以下はwindowsでは問題にならないのでしょうか。

```
>> save('Aarray.txt', 'A')
>> sample
Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file Aarray.txt must be the same as previous lines.

Error in sample (line 1)
Aarray = load('Aarray.txt')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save`と`load`のヘルプを読めばわかると思いますが、`save`でファイルフォーマットを指定しないと、データを`.mat`という独自形式のバイナリファイルに書き出します。しかし、`save`で書き出すときに、拡張子を`.m`としています。これは、MATLABのソースコードの拡張子でテキストフォーマットなので、`load`がデータフォーマットを誤解してうまく読み込めていないようです。

データをテキストでセーブするのなら、

```
save('Aarray.txt', 'A', '-ascii')

Aarray = load('Aarray.txt')
```

としてください。

---

ちなみに、MATLABのソースコード以外に`.m`の拡張子を付けるのは、お勧めしません。MATLABに限ったことではありませんが、拡張子を想定された使い方以外に使うと、いろいろと問題が起きます。

Comment: ご回答を受けて質問に追記させていただきました。

Comment: @NPP 私の回答には、データフォーマットを指定するための引数`'-ascii'`を`save`に追加しているのですが、見落としたのでしょうか。

Comment: 見落としておりました。申し訳ございません。